# Bash arithmetic expression (( in compound statement [[ returns true?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, math, expression

Simple arithmetic expression enclosed in '((' evaluates to true when inside compound conditional expression '[['

```
HAVE_SRC=1
[[ (( $HAVE_SRC == 1 )) && -d $( pwd ) ]]
echo $? # returns 0 => true

HAVE_SRC=0
[[ (( $HAVE_SRC == 1 )) && -d $( pwd ) ]]
echo $? # returns 1 => false

HAVE_SRC=1
[[ (( $HAVE_SRC )) && -d $( pwd ) ]]
echo $? # returns 0 => true
```

**PROBLEM:**

```
HAVE_SRC=0
[[ (( $HAVE_SRC )) && -d $( pwd ) ]]
echo $? # returns 0 => true ????
```

Comment: in some languages zeros and things like empty arrays, string or so are considered to be false, in some other languages they are considered to be true. the ruby and lua semantics for example counts only nil's and false as false, other any object is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `(( ... ))` inside of `[[ ... ]]`:

```
(( HAVE_SRC == 1 )) && [[ -d $pwd ]]
```

To see how bash interprets the expressions you gave, try running them with

```
set -xv
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if I want to do the following?

    `[[ $# -eq 0 || ( $NO_BUILD -eq 1 && -z $HOST ) ]] && usage`

I want to change the part with –eq to == and use ((…))

Comment: With option `set –xv` it’s clear that `[[ (( HAVE_SRC )) ]]` is converted to `[[ -n HAVE_SRC ]]` meaning string is not null. That doesn’t seam ok to me

Comment: @FarkasSzilard: You probably mean  `if (( ! $# )) || ( (( NO_BUILD == 1 )) && [[ -z $HOST ]] ) ; then usage ; fi`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks